# Outlook 2016 not opening, TeamViewer / VNC related?

Tags: vnc, teamviewer, microsoft-outlook-2016

I've never seen an issue like this one! Can someone please offer some ideas?

Outlook 2016 connected to an Office 365 email account.

When the user opens Outlook 2016 it gets stuck on the blue "loading profile" screen.

However if the PC is being remotely accessed, either via VNC or TeamViewer 11, Outlook opens immediately without issue.

I have tried the following, but the issue persists:

Disabling Outlook add-ins

Recreating the Outlook profile

Removing VNC and TeamViewer

Comment: Any other add-ins Outlook might be loading? PDF creators, Antivirus add-ins etc.

Comment: I unchecked all add-ins. However Outlook would still load if I was remotely assisting, whether add-ins were enabled or not.

Comment: Stumped as well 

Comment: How about offline? If the machine is physically disconnected from any network, can Outlook open?

Answer (score -2):

desactivate "hardware acceleration" in Outlook advanced options

Comment: That could be right. With an active remote session of some kind Outlook might do this automatically. This would imply though that Outlook never worked normally on that computer in the first place, or that the problem started after an update of the display-drivers. See also https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2768648/display-issues-in-office-client-applications

Comment: This could potentially be the correct answer. Can you elaborate more why you suggested this, and why this should answer the question?